# How to insert appendices in a book class document under a given latex template?--Xelatex compiler

Tags: templates, books, thesis, appendix

I am using a latex template to complete my thesis. **I would like to insert appendix in my thesis, like "Appendix A, Appendix B". I would very appreciate if someone tell me how to insert appendices.**

I tried several methods to insert appendix but they don't work as disired. When using the following command

```
\appendix
\chapter{test}
```

in the "appendices.tex" file, it can not be compiled and output the wrong message below.

> Underfull \vbox (badness 1803) has occurred while \output is active [131])
> [132] (tex/appendices.tex
> ....1...
> Runaway argument?
> {
> ! Paragraph ended before @chapter was complete.
>
> \par

I tried the command `\section{test}`, but it also can not be compiled. I also tried to use the package `\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}`. In this case, the appendix can be generated. However, it can not satisfy the format requirement of the thesis, so I guess it would be better to use the command given by the template itself.

I check the related command in the `.sty` file of the template (the related code are given below). I would very appreciate if someone tell me how to insert appendices by using this template

```
\def\appendix{
        \if@firstappendix
     \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
     \setcounter{section}{0}%
     \renewcommand\@chapapp{Appendix}
     \typeout{....\AppendicesTotal...}
     \ifnum\AppendicesTotal=1
         \renewcommand\chaptername{\appendixnamenonumber}
     \else
         \renewcommand\chaptername{\appendixname}
     \fi
     \@firstappendixfalse
  \fi
  \chapter}%

\def\AppendicesTotal{0}

\def\AppendicesNumber#1{\gdef\AppendicesTotal{#1}}

\AtEndDocument{
  \if@firstappendix
  \else
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\AppendicesNumber{\thechapter}}
  \fi}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't show only some code snippets. We cannot try out such snippets without guessing. Always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. And if you use a template, please either reduce it also to the code really needed or at least—but only as a compromise—add a link to it. Because you've not done and therefore I cannot really test, the following *is guessing*:

In your case, the definition of `\appendix` ends with `\chapter`. So `\appendix` is not a switch like the `\appendix` of the standard classes but a command like `\chapter` itself. It expects at least one argument. So you should *not use*:

```
\appendix
\chapter{test}
```

but:

```
\appendix{test}
```

and same for all further appendices, like shown here:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@firstappendix\@firstappendixtrue
\def\appendix{
        \if@firstappendix
     \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
     \setcounter{section}{0}%
     \renewcommand\@chapapp{Appendix}
     \typeout{....\AppendicesTotal...}
     \ifnum\AppendicesTotal=1
         \renewcommand\chaptername{\appendixnamenonumber}
     \else
         \renewcommand\chaptername{\appendixname}
     \fi
     \@firstappendixfalse
  \fi
  \chapter}%

\def\AppendicesTotal{0}

\def\AppendicesNumber#1{\gdef\AppendicesTotal{#1}}

\AtEndDocument{
  \if@firstappendix
  \else
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\AppendicesNumber{\thechapter}}
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main}
\appendix{Appendix}
\appendix{One more Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem has been solved.